# Unity Google Play Games Android - How to get Current Player's Score and the score above it

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I'm using the Google Play Games Unity plugin for Android, and I'm trying to achieve 2 things.

1. Get the current player's score
2. Get the score of the player directly above the current player (unless they're in 1st place)

I've seen some examples here of how to do it in plain Android, but I'm not sure how to do this with the Unity plugin.

Any leads? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Did you ever achieve this?